# Deno allow all permissions

Tags: deno

I often find myself typing at least two or three permission options when playing with Deno:

```sh
deno run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-env app.ts
```

There's a way to escape explicit permissions.

Comment: Is it a good practice to pick up a trending topic and ask a question and answer them all by yourself in less than a minute.??

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag yes, in fact it is encouraged: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag I won't get points for accepting my own answer, that is not how it works. Please be aware of the link that I sent you, and that when creating a question there's an option to answer it right away. It's a common community practice.

Comment: oh okay. I hope your answer helps the community.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use: `--allow-all` or the short option `-A` to allow all permissions.

Have in mind that it will include all of the following permissions:

- `--allow-env=<allow-env>` Allow environment access for things like getting and setting of environment variables. Since Deno 1.9, you can specify an optional, comma-separated list of environment variables to provide an allow-list of allowed environment variables.
- `--allow-hrtime` Allow high-resolution time measurement. High-resolution time can be used in timing attacks and fingerprinting.
- `--allow-net=<allow-net>` Allow network access. You can specify an optional, comma-separated list of IP addresses or hostnames (optionally with ports) to provide an allow-list of allowed network addresses.
- `--allow-ffi` Allow loading of dynamic libraries. Be aware that dynamic libraries are not run in a sandbox and therefore do not have the same security restrictions as the Deno process. Therefore, use with caution. Please note that `--allow-ffi` is an unstable feature.
- `--allow-read=<allow-read>` Allow file system read access. You can specify an optional, comma-separated list of directories or files to provide an allow-list of allowed file system access.
- `--allow-run=<allow-run>` Allow running subprocesses. Since Deno 1.9, You can specify an optional, comma-separated list of subprocesses to provide an allow-list of allowed subprocesses. Be aware that subprocesses are not run in a sandbox and therefore do not have the same security restrictions as the Deno process. Therefore, use with caution.
- `--allow-write=<allow-write>` Allow file system write access. You can specify an optional, comma-separated list of directories or files to provide an allow-list of allowed file system access.

Answer (score 4):

There's a nice option `-A` to allow all permissions.

```sh
deno run -A app.ts
```

**Important:** This is *insecure* and should be used for experimentation only.

When developing real applications prefer explicit permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool that aims to help with that https://github.com/BentoumiTech/denox/

You can specify your scripts in a `deno-workspace.yml` file with permissions list

```
scripts:
  # "denox run start" will execute app.ts with --allow-net --allow-read --allow-env permissions
  start:
    file: app.ts
    deno_options:
      allow-net: true 
      allow-read: true
      allow-env: true
```

`$ deno install -Af -n denox https://denopkg.com/BentoumiTech/denox/denox.ts`

`$ denox run start` will translate to `deno run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-env app.ts`

It also supports all the other deno options

```
allow-all, allow-env, allow-hrtime, allow-net, allow-plugin, allow-read, allow-run,
allow-write, cached-only, cert, config, importmap, inspect, inspect-brk, lock, lock-write,
log-level, no-remote, quiet, reload, seed, unstable, v8-flags
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use denon https://deno.land/x/denon, is a tool like nodemon. An awesome thing about this is that includes a denon.json where you can add the attribute "allow": as an array and add the flags you want.

```
"allow": ["net", "read", "write"]
```

and then in the terminal run the script for start your application

```
denon start yourapp.ts
```

This will run:

```
deno run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-write yourapp.ts
```

Now, when you make a change and save, it will run it again.

It has other cool attributes to add like the `"unstable": true`. Give it a try and read the README from denon for more information.